# Can`t assign the AD user account as an identity to the application pool

Tags: windows, active-directory, iis

Once i tried to assign the AD user as an identity to the application pool, i am constantly getting application pool stops on the first request. When i select ApplicationPoolIdentity everything goes ok. I have not seen any errors in the event viewer. How can i get some sort of logs to see whats happened? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If an application pool crashes, the event will be logged in the "Application" section of the Windows Event Log, with added information about what happened (usually some kind of exception). You should start your troubleshooting there.

The most common reason for a web application not working under a different identity is the user account not having proper access to something (such as a folder or file, but it could also be a database or a network share, depending on what the application actually does and how).

Also, if you are using Kerberos authentication, the SPN for the web application needs to be manually assigned to the user account running the application pool.

Comment: so if i have trouble with authentification there are no logs in event viewer because this is not the app crash, right? and if there are no logs in event viewer - there are no logs at all?

Comment: Does the application pool even *start*? What happens if you start it manually?

Comment: if i start it manually, all the thing is happened is a replacement of an icon with a "stop" button with a regular one. how can i check whether it was really started or not?

Comment: In the same window, there is a "status" column which tells if the pool is started or stopped. If the user account can't log on (f.e. because you typed the wrong credentials) the application pool would not even start.

Comment: If the application pool starts and then it stops when processing a request, then this is a crash and it *will* be reported in the Application event log.